# CSS class not getting reflected in the table

Tags: php, html, css

I have values in table on which upon click I want to set a particular class and navigate to a certain page.
The table looks like this:

```
    <?php
// Form the page file name
if($content_type == "")  {
    $content_type = "wtc";  
}
?>

<table border='0' width='250' class='navigation'>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' valign='right' class=<?php if($content_type == "wtc") echo 'active'; ?>><a href='?page=wtc'>Create WTC Server</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' valign='right' class=<?php if($content_type == "rap") echo 'active'; ?>><a href='?page=rap'>Create RAP</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' valign='right' class=<?php if($content_type == "lap") echo 'active'; ?>><a href='?page=lap'>Create LAP</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' valign='right' class=<?php if($content_type == "import") echo 'active'; ?>><a href='?page=import'>Import Services</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' valign='right' class=<?php if($content_type == "export") echo 'active'; ?>><a href='?page=export'>Export Services</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here the thing is it is navigating to another page but the class is not set on the value when it is clicked on.

Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to look before at the `page` value into the `$_GET` array

```
// read page parameter (if it exists)
$content_type = @$_GET['page'];

// it's better to always sanitize a bit any user input
$content_type = htmlspecialchars($content_type);

if ($content_type == "")  {
    $content_type = "wtc";  
}
```

since when you click you're actually passing the `page` parameter by the querystring

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway I would strongly suggest to restrict the admittable user input only to `wtc`, `rap`, `lap`, `...` - Don't allow more than the necessary and check if the value passed is one of those existant